# Returning API result in separate values

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a simple price listener through Coingecko API through this code:

```
from pycoingecko import CoinGeckoAPI

cg = CoinGeckoAPI()
cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd')

print(cg.get_price)
```

But I get the following error message:

> <bound method list_args_to_comma_separated..input_args of
> <pycoingecko.api.CoinGeckoAPI object at 0x0000017E6EA13940>>

I understand that the output should be: **{'bitcoin': {'usd': 3462.04}}**

So how can I make it tell the token name alone and the price in USD alone too?

Comment: You forgot to call your function with parenthesis at the end

You should write `print(cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd'))`

Comment: also, that isnt an error

Comment: thank you, but why the -1??? The documentation was like that....

Comment: Can you share the documentation link ? Found this one https://github.com/man-c/pycoingecko#examples and it's pretty clear :) yoy even have the EXACT code to get your output

Comment: In fact I'l very suprised : you called the `get_price` very nicely on 3rd line, but then you do something vey strange on 4th line, you print the method ITSELF, you don't call it, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenters are pointing out, you didn't call the function properly. Either write `print(cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd'))` at the end, or assign the value of `cg.get_price(ids='bitcoin', vs_currencies='usd')` to a variable, and print that variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a call of the function to variable and then have access to it's data in dict type